# excel pivot table sorting

Tags: excel-2010, pivot-table

How pivot table sorts data in row label and column label

It resulted quite strange to me.

as source sheet has a column with data in format "year month week" (e.g 2012 10 wk 4) as text data

when using this column as row label and column label in pivot it resulted as

2012 08 wk 4
2012 09  wk 1
2012 09  wk 4
2012 09  wk 3
2012 09  wk 2

source sheet has data in correct order 2012 09 wk 1, wk 2, wk 3, wk 4... but when using it in pivot table disturbs the order which should be as in source sheet

Answer (score 1):

You might need to right-click on the say the first row where a value you wish to sort appears (eg where it says '2012 08 wk 4') and choose the sort menu option from the right-click menu.

In the image below, I right-clicked on the value 896,321......

[image]

Comment: Thanx user381624 but it will bring April and August at first, actual column value is 2012 August wk 4 ....

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix that.  I had a similar problem where the data was being sourced from a ssas cube.  If I put months as columns it would display the columns in alphabetical order, however I was able to fix this in the ssas cube definition by telling it to use the month number as the ordinal.  If your data isn't coming from a ssas cube, I don't know what to suggest.